# Ag-grid, Way to get grid dom element inside cell renderer

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I want to get Grid dom element inside of cell renderer. It is possible?

It because I have to append my component to Grid DOM through createPortal method.

But I don't know how to get grid element inside custom cell renderer.I guess It is can be found inside of ICellRendererParams, but I can not find.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? Do you want to append a component in the cell itself or to the body but positioned next to the cell?

Comment: @rateLess 
I just want to append my component to grid instead of body. It because I want to my absolute component always attached to grid when the page is scolled.

Comment: But what is your use case? Are you trying to do something like open a menu inside the grid when you click a button in a cell?

Comment: @rateLess

Something similar. It is a kind of popup that is open when user click image inside of cell. 

Actually I want to open popup only inside cell, but it is hidden by grid element. So I decided to append my popup on grid instead..
If there is the way to be shown my popup inside cell. It is the best way to me

Answer (score 1):

I've put a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cdn-53eds?file=/src/CustomCellRenderer.js). It uses ReactDOM's `createPortal` to append or remove a `<div>` on `document.body` when clicking on a button. Its position is `absolute` in order to use the `top` and `left` properties so I can position the div right next to the button.

I've put the `popupRef` there to compute its width upon rendering, so that I could offset the popup more to the left. Otherwise, it would completely cover the button due to overlapping corners. `setWidth(0)` to see what I mean.

You may use a library like [Popper](https://popper.js.org/) if it makes it easier for you to position the popup.

Comment: Yes this is the only way I also found. Thanks!